# How to use Gazebo Ignition NavSat plugin

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, gps, gazebo-ignition

I'm trying to use the Navsat plugin but I can't get it working. I'm using ros-humble

I've been following the link below, but I am unable to see any navsat topic in gazebo
https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/28643/gps-sensor-plugin-in-ignition/

In my robot urdf, I have the following code

```
    <link name="chassis">
            ....
      <plugin filename="ignition-gazebo-navsat-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::NavSat"/>
      <gazebo>
        <sensor name="navsat_sensor" type="navsat">
          <always_on>1</always_on>
          <update_rate>1</update_rate>
          <topic>navsat</topic>
        </sensor>
     </gazebo>
    </link>
```

On my world sdf, I also included

```
    <world name="field">
        ...
      <spherical_coordinates>
        <surface_model>EARTH_WGS84</surface_model>
        <world_frame_orientation>ENU</world_frame_orientation>
        <latitude_deg>-22.986687</latitude_deg>
        <longitude_deg>-43.202501</longitude_deg>
        <elevation>0</elevation>
        <heading_deg>0</heading_deg>
      </spherical_coordinates>
    </world>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `<plugin>` should be in the world SDF file (see [example](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/ign-gazebo6/examples/worlds/spherical_coordinates.sdf)).
2. The `<gazebo>` tag should be directly under `<robot>` in a URDF file and should reference the link it's modifying. In your case, it should be `<gazebo reference="chassis">`. You can refer to [this](http://sdformat.org/tutorials?tut=sdformat_urdf_extensions&cat=specification&) documentation for more details on the `<gazebo>` tag.

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution.

Beside the navsat plugin, other plugins has to be in the world sdf file or else gazebo can't load the world file properly

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If there are no plugins in `<world>`, Gazebo assumes you want to load the default plugins in `~/.gz/sim/<version>/server.config`, but if you specify one plugin, it will assume you are overriding the default plugins, so you'll have to put all the world plugins you need.